# How to distinguish direct object and object complement?

Tags: direct-objects, noun-phrases, object-complements

Could anyone please tell me how to distinguish a direct object from an object complement?
Do the two have any radical differences?

In the sentence, "Our childhood experiences have made us what we are", is "what we are" a noun clause? Does it serve as a direct object or an object complement?

Answer (score 4):

> Our childhood experiences have made us what we are.

**Us** is the direct object.

*What we are* is the object complement. It complements or "completes" the direct object.

Yes, *what we are* is a noun phrase.

An object complement can be a noun, noun phrase, pronoun, or adjective.

Verbs such as make and create, and those such as name, call, and label often have object complements.

I named **my daughter.**

I named **my daughter** *Alice.*

The other students called **April** *smart.*

Josephine painted **her elephant** *pink.*

We elected **Obama** *president.*

The cats considered **the dry food** *poison.*

The witness called **everything he saw** *a complete mess.*

What distinguishes the direct object from the object complement?

The direct object takes the action of the verb. It comes **before** any object complement. To identify the direct object of a sentence, find the verb and ask "verb what?" or "verb who?" See [this page](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/direct_object.htm).

Everything in **bold** is a direct object.

The object complement comes after the direct object. The words in *italics* are object complements.

Note that the order of words can change which noun is the direct object and which is the object complement. D.O. comes first.

I called **my daughter** *Alice.*

I called **who**?
I called **my daughter**. DO is **my daughter.**
*Alice* is OC.

I called **Alice** *my daughter.*

I called **who**?
I called **Alice**. DO is **Alice**.
*my daughter* is OC.

The city planners considered **the plan** *amazing beyond belief.*

Josephine found **the homework she had done** *lying in the trash can.*

Josephine found **what**?
**the homework she had done** is D.O. *lying in the trash can* is object complement.

> Our childhood experiences have made **us** *what we are.*

Made **who**?
Made **us** (direct object) 
*what we are* is object complement.

[This page](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/object_complement.htm) has more examples.